# Creating an endpoint for filtering name, price and availability

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, webapi

I have the following `[HttpGet]` request that is suppose to filter name, price and availability of product.

I don't know where I am getting it wrong.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ProductDTO>>> GetProducts([FromQuery] ProductParams productParams)
{
    var queryable = _context.Products.AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productParams.Name) || !productParams.Price.HasValue || !productParams.IsAvailable.HasValue)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Name == productParams.Name || x.Price == productParams.Price ||
                x.IsAvailable == productParams.IsAvailable);
    }

    return await _context.Products
                .Select(x => productsDTO(x))
                .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hi @gidmak,any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code like following:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ProductDTO>>> GetProducts([FromQuery] ProductParams productParams)
    {
          var query = _context.Products.AsQueryable();
    
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productParams.Name))
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.Name== productParams.Name);
        }

        if (productParams.Price.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(p =>p.Price == productParams.Price);
        }

        if (productParams.IsAvailable.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.IsAvailable == productParams.IsAvailable);
        }
        return await query.Select(x => productsDTO(x)).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`HasValue` checks if object is not null. Your if condition is false, you should remove exclamation marks from `HasValue` and I think if you add null checks it will be better.

It should be like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productParams.Name) || 
    productParams?.Price.HasValue || 
    productParams?.IsAvailable.HasValue)
{
    queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Name == productParams.Name || x.Price == productParams.Price ||
                x.IsAvailable == productParams.IsAvailable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, didn't work as desired